# Sending React Native Notification on database update?

Tags: postgresql, react-native, push-notification, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I have an AWS Postgres database, an API layer, and a React Native application. One user is trying to communicate with another (and this will be stored in the db) I want to let the intended user know that a message awaits them with a notification. I'm not using expo. I've looked at using OneSignal but the functionality seems limited in this aspect (unless I'm missing something) I've prefer to use React Native Local notifications. Does anybody know how to achieve this with either OneSignal or RNLC?

Answer (score 0):

You want 2 users to communicate with each other, and via a notification to let them know they have a new message. You can send push notifications directly to a user by using the player id and our REST API. The player id will target only the user the notification was meant to be sent to.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification